# pandas how to replace only empty list data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

my dataframe look like this:

```
   variations_list1          variations_list2
    ["yellow","ornage"]          []
    ["xl","xxl"]                 []
    ["Burger","pizza"]         ["$25","$30"]
```

expected dataframe:

```
 variations_list1          variations_list2
    ["yellow","ornage"]         ["yellow","ornage"] #filling emty list with current row data
    ["xl","xxl"]                ["xl","xxl"]
    ["Burger","pizza"]         ["$25","$30"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do

```
df.loc[~df['variations_list2'].astype(bool),'variations_list2'] = df['variations_list1']
```

You have the same issue like before, list is not list

```
df.loc[df['variations_list2']=='[]','variations_list2'] = df['variations_list1']
```

Comment: it's filling  all row of 'variations_list2' but I need to fill only empty list row.`["Burger","pizza"]` have value `["$25","$30"]` so I don't need to replace value of  `["$25","$30"]`

Comment: @boyenec check update

Comment: tried but still now same result. it's replacing all value even those are not empty list

Comment: @boyenec it work from my side , you may need to check your column type

Comment: I checked column type and it's `object`